# Any smart tricks to simplify my nasty integration?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, matlab

I am trying to solve for the following unpleasant integral

$$\int_{\gamma}^{\infty}  \bigg[t- \int_{-2}^{2}\frac{ t \ f_X(x)}{1+N  \ \big|G(x)\big|^2 \ t^{-3}}\ dx\bigg]  \ dt$$

where  $N$ is a non-negative integer for example 16 and where

\begin{align}
G(x) = \frac{1}{N} \text{exp} \bigg( j \pi x \frac{(N -1)}{2}\bigg) \frac{\sin (\pi \frac{N}{2} x)}{\sin   (\frac{\pi}{2} x )}
\end{align} G is a sinc function.

And where $$f_X(x) =\int_{\max\{-1,-1-x\}}^{\min\{1,1-x\}} \left(\frac{1}{\pi^2 \sqrt{1-(x+y)^2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\right) dy $$

**Solution**

The way I do this is

1- Using MATLAB  I first numerically integrate $f_X(x)$ i.e integrate over $y$ and keep it in terms of x

2- then I do Reimann sum for my inner integral: $$x=-2:0.1:2$$

$$\sum_i \frac{ t \, \  f_X(x_i)}{1+N \ t^{-3} \ |G(x_i)|^2} \times 0.1$$

3- I symbolically integrate for t

**Question**

Do you have any nice smart tricks to simplify? or any approximation?

Comment: This looks nasty indeed. Do you mind telling the source of it? I doubt there will be a symbolically integration available. $f_X(x)$ involves elliptic functions.

Comment: Thanks mickep, I know it does, but my research for some reason made me reach it. I work with wireless communication applications, and I was solving for laplace transform of a random variable. That random variable is itself a function of a poisson point process and the function I described above with pdf $f_X(x)$. the reason you see this shape of integral is due to probability generating function of PPP @mickep does this make sense?

Comment: Sorry, I see no obvious simplifications that can be done. Thanks for sharing the background. I would do some numerical integration if I had to compute this.

Comment: thanks, do you agree with the way I tackle it with my solution above? @mickep

Comment: Looks OK, but maybe one should be careful with convergence at infinity?

Comment: You see this G function is almost a piecewise function its either one or zero (approximately). If you make this approximation the integral would simplify nicely. however I am trying not to simplify...@mickep